# Output of Join in Apache Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink

In Apache Flink, if I join two data sets on one primary key I get a tuple 2 containing the corresponding data set entry out each of the data sets.

The problem is, when applying a the `map()` method to the outcoming tuple 2 data set it does not really look nice, especially if the entries of both data sets have a high number of features.

Using tuples in both input data sets gets me some code like this:

```
var in1: DataSet[(Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)] = /* */
var in2: DataSet[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = /* */

val out = in1.join(in2).where(0, 1, 2).equalTo(0, 1, 2)
  .map(join => (join._1._1, join._1._2, join._1._3,
                    join._1._4, join._1._5, join._2._4))
```

I would not mind using POJOs or case classes, but I don't see how this would make it better.

**Question 1:** Is there a nice way to flaten that tuple 2? E.g. using another operator.

**Question 2:** How to handle a join of 3 data sets on the same key? It would make the example source even more messy.

*Thanks for helping.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can directly apply a join function on each pair of joined elements such as for example

```
val leftData: DataSet[(String, Int, Int)] = ...
val rightData: DataSet[(String, Int)] = ...
val joined: DataSet[(String, Int, Int)] = leftData
      .join(rightData).where(0).equalTo(0) { (l, r) => (l._1, l._2, l._3 + r._2) ) }
```

To answer the second question, Flink handles only binary joins. However, Flink's optimizer can avoid to do unnecessary shuffles, if you give a hint about the behavior of your function. [Forward Field annotations](http://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/programming_guide.html#semantic-annotations) tell the optimizer, that certain fields (such as the join key) have not been modified by your join function and enables reusing existing partitioning and sortings.